# emacs 27 systemd service inherit environment variables

Tags: bash, systemd, environment-variables, emacs

On Ubuntu 18.04, running emacs 27, emacs installs a systemd config

```
$ cat ~/.config/systemd/user/default.target.wants/emacs.service 
[Unit]
Description=Emacs text editor
Documentation=info:emacs man:emacs(1) https://gnu.org/software/emacs/

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/emacs --fg-daemon
ExecStop=/usr/local/bin/emacsclient --eval "(kill-emacs)"
Environment=SSH_AUTH_SOCK=%t/keyring/ssh
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

But when I start emacsclient as I have always done in the past (using previous versions of emacs/ubuntu), my environment variables are no longer imported. How can modify the service to import environment variables configured in my shell init files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run a login shell before executing the emacs binary in order to read and parse your environment. Like so:

```
ExecStart=/bin/bash -l -c 'exec /usr/local/bin/emacs --fg-daemon'
```

By default, systemd executes all commands in a clean environment, in order to provide consistency and reproducible service runtime environments. So, if you need additional environment settings, you usually need to set those up yourself.